# Add another node in create content Drupal 6

Tags: 7, nodes

I am searching for a way to add content in node/add/page (for example) with a "Create another node (of this content type)" button. The button would add another form, and when the forms are submitted, Drupal would create 2 nodes.

Is there already a module that does this? How can I differently achieve this?

Comment: do you want to create multiple nodes at the same time ? or is it something like a multiple forms linked to a same node ?

Comment: I want to get create multiple nodes at the same time, but on the same page, (like a multiple values field.. but than for nodes)

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Multi Node add](http://drupal.org/project/multi_node_add) module.

> This module provides a new interface for creating nodes where the
>   users are able to select the fields what they want to use for creating
>   the nodes.